# How do I accept an input from the Output Console in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, debugging

I am trying to run a simple Rock Paper Scissors code in Python. Here is the code

```
    import random
    
    def get_choices():
        player_choice = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors: ")
        options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
        computer_choice = random.choice(options)
        choices = {"player": player_choice, "computer": computer_choice}    
        return choices
    
    choices = get_choices()
    print(choices)
```

When I ran the code via Run Code , the code ran properly showing the input "Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors:" in the Output Console, but when I tried to input the response (ex. rock) it did not allow me to type in the Output console, however, when I ran the code via Run Python file, I could write my input in the Terminal Console. [Here is a screenshot of the output console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqO3K.jpg) I cannot write anything in here, but I can write in the Terminal Console [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dhmx.jpg).

I tried using the Run and Debug feature but that did not fix the issue. The only thing which is close to a solution is simply only using the Terminal console and running the python file. I would really prefer to use the output console as it is less clogged than the Terminal console. If it helps, I downloaded Python through the Windows store and running python --version in cmd prompt works fine. I also use Code Runner. Any help is appreciated <3

Comment: I think that, as the name says, the output console might be only for STDOUT, not for STDIN.

Comment: So is there no way for me to write in the Output section?

Comment: I do not know, but do not think so. What prevents you from running the code mannually ?

Comment: nothing prevents me from running the code, in fact it worked fine! just that the input can only be taken in the terminal console

Comment: Output is for output only Jasmine. Typing `clear` and hitting the return key will tidy up the terminal for you.